# Forzar descarga (Download Manager Android) en redes sin acceso a internet

Tags: java, android

Existe alguna forma de cambiar el comportamiento del download manager cuando android detectar que la conexión no tiene acceso a Internet? Mi aplicación trabaja en un entorno privado, se conecta a una wifi pero está no tiene acceso a Internet.

Estoy implementando la descarga de archivos en un webview pero no funciona porque la wifi no tiene acceso a Internet, sin embargo si me desconecto de la wifi y activo los datos móviles dónde si hay Internet automáticamente me sale la descarga pendiente y comenzar a intentar descargar...

O sea que mi código funciona, solo me falta decirle al download manager que no verifique el estado de la conexión.
Alguna solución?

Este es mi código para la descarga

```
webview1.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        //for downloading directly through download manager
        final DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setMimeType(mimetype);

        //------------------------COOKIE------------------------
        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
        //------------------------COOKIE------------------------
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.setDescription("Descargando archivo...");
        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
        final DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        new Thread("Browser download") {
            public void run() {
                dm.enqueue(request);
            }
        }.start(); Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Descarga iniciada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

La app siempre va a estar en una red sin acceso a internet, es una red privada sin acceso a internet. Las descargas se realizarán desde una web alojada en esa red, no desde internet. O sea que como dije antes, la app siempre va a funcionar en ese estado, sin internet. Lo que necesito es que la descarga se inicie en ese estado y no espere a que exista acceso a internet porque de existir sería porque ya estaría fuera de esa red privada y la descarga nunca encontrará el servidor...

Comment: Si la app va a estar sin acceso a internet no es posible iniciar una descarga sin internet. :-( me imagino te refieres a solo descargar desde una red privada.

Comment: No soy el más indicado para afirmar que sí se puede pero los navegadores lo hacen aún en esas condiciones. O sea, estando conectado a la red WiFi que como he dicho no tiene acceso a internet, accedo a la web alojada dentro de esa red mediante el Chrome, doy click en el enlace de la descarga y si se inicia y descarga perfectamente...

Comment: cual es el url? es http o https, o ftp o algo diferente?

Comment: El URL comienza con http:// y como decía anteriormente, hice la prueba con el navegador (Chrome) y la descarga si se inicia.

Comment: Tenemos el mismo problema. ¿lo habéis solucionado?
Una opción que barajamos es abrir internet pero sólo para que DownloadManager vea que hay internet, capando todas las demás, pero no sabemos a qué url accede o si es suficiente con activar una url cualquiera.
Gracias

Comment: La solución está en gestionar la descarga desde la misma aplicación. O sea, prescindir de Download Manager y hacer que la propia aplicación sea capaz de manejar las descargas, con su propio progressbar etc. Enfócate hacia ahí, esa fue la solución en ese proyecto. No te puedo dar código de ejemplo porque hace tiempo que salí de ese proyecto. Busca información al respecto.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/307776/142689