# Error con Descarga URLConnection (android)

Tags: android

Estoy intentando de implementar mi propio gestor de descargas, aún me faltan varias cosas pero en este caso quiero ayuda en algo en concreto.

Hice algunas pruebas, la descarga funciona correctamente pero me pregunté que pasaría si se cae la conexión?

Al hacer la prueba mi aplicación se cerró y me lanzó un mensaje de error en doInBackground cómo puedo solucionar esto? Aquí está mi código.

```
        webview2.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            FileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
            new DownloadFile().execute(Uri.parse(url).toString());
        }
    });
}
    private AlertDialog downloadDialog;
    private View downloadInflate;
    private ProgressBar downloadProgress;
    private Button downloadCancel;
    private java.io.File PathDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    private String FileName = "";
    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AcercaDeActivity.this).create();
            downloadInflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_loading, null);
            downloadProgress = (ProgressBar) downloadInflate.findViewById(R.id.progressbar1);
            downloadCancel = (Button) downloadInflate.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            downloadCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View downloadCancel) {
                        downloadDialog.setCancelable(true);
                        downloadDialog.dismiss();
                        showMessage("Descarga Cancelada");
                    }
                });
            downloadDialog.setView(downloadInflate);
            downloadDialog.setMessage("Descargando " + FileName);
            downloadDialog.setCancelable(false);
            downloadDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            downloadProgress.setIndeterminate(false);
            downloadProgress.setMax(100);
            downloadDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... Url) {
            try {
                java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(Url[0]);
                java.net.URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
                java.io.InputStream input = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                java.io.OutputStream output = new java.io.FileOutputStream(PathDir + "/" + FileName);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024]; long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                showMessage(e.getMessage().toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } return null;
        }

        @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
                downloadProgress.setProgress(progress[0]);
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            downloadDialog.setCancelable(true);
            downloadDialog.dismiss();
            showMessage("Descarga Completada");
        }
```

Quisiera además que si hay algún problema con la conexión la descarga esperara unos segundos, incluso sin perder los datos descargados para continuar con la descarga si en ese tiempo vuelve la estabilidad en la conexión.

De lo contrario que lanzar un cuadro de diálogo con las opciones cancelar y reintentar y si presiono cancelar que cancele la tarea y borre el trozo de archivo descargado.
Espero alguien me pueda ayudar o al menos guiar...

Comment: Hola, es importante agregar el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat para determinar una correcta solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de buscar un poco encontré el problema. Estaba intentando mostrar un mensaje desde doInBackground y este no debe ocuparse para interactuar con el UI.

Esta era la línea errónea.
`showMessage(e.getMessage().toString());`

También logré implementar que detecte si se cae la conexión y en consecuencia me envíe muestre un mensaje y elimine el trozo de archivo que había descargado.

Ahora mi código de ve así

```
    webview2.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            FileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
            new DownloadFile().execute(Uri.parse(url).toString());
        }
    });
}
    private AlertDialog downloadDialog;
    private View downloadInflate;
    private ProgressBar downloadProgress;
    private Button downloadCancel;
    private java.io.File PathDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    private String FileName = "";
    private int fileSizeProgress;
    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AcercaDeActivity.this).create();
            downloadInflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_loading, null);
            downloadProgress = (ProgressBar) downloadInflate.findViewById(R.id.progressbar1);
            downloadCancel = (Button) downloadInflate.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            downloadCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View downloadCancel) {
                        downloadDialog.setCancelable(true);
                        downloadDialog.dismiss();
                        showMessage("Descarga Cancelada");
                    }
                });
            downloadDialog.setView(downloadInflate);
            downloadDialog.setMessage("Descargando " + FileName);
            downloadDialog.setCancelable(false);
            downloadDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            downloadProgress.setIndeterminate(false);
            downloadProgress.setMax(100);
            downloadDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... Url) {
            try {
                java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(Url[0]);
                java.net.URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
                java.io.InputStream input = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                java.io.OutputStream output = new java.io.FileOutputStream(PathDir + "/" + FileName);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024]; long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } return null;
        }

        @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
                downloadProgress.setProgress(progress[0]);
                fileSizeProgress = progress[0];
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            if (fileSizeProgress != 100) {
                showMessage("Error: No se pudo completar la descarga");
                java.io.File file = new java.io.File(PathDir + "/" + FileName);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();
                }
            } else {
                showMessage("Descarga Completada");
            }
            downloadDialog.setCancelable(true);
            downloadDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Lo que sigue ahora, como decía en la pregunta es implementar tiempo de espera si se cae la conexión sin perder los datos descargados para continuar con la descarga si en ese tiempo vuelve la estabilidad en la conexión y de lo contrario lanzar un cuadro de diálogo con las opciones cancelar y reintentar.

No sé si para eso debo hacer una pregunta nueva, no conozco mucho de foros. Si alguien me puede ayudar estaría muy agradecido.